# How can I provide/return link to existing entity when using UniqueEntity in Symfony?

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, doctrine, symfony

I have a entity set with UniqueEntity as follows:

```
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"}, message="Note: That article name already exists.")
```

If I try to create a article with a name that already exists then that message does get displayed. How can I provide a link to the user to the existing article at this point?

I'm not sure what code to include so if there's anything I can include please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: I should also note that I read in the documentation that {{ value }} can be used in the message but that would only use the name of the article... I'd need the ID to create a link.